# Connecting to Azure SQL database from desktop app in Python: authorization with Azure AD

Tags: python, sql, azure, pyodbc, multi-factor-authentication

I have a desktop app written in Python which uploads some data to an SQL database (SQL Server) hosted on Azure. The access is authenticated using Azure AD MFA. The application uses pyodbc. This is a bit cumbersome because I need to type in my password and authorization code every time I use the application. I want the application to get authenticated automatically. I do not want to use some simple workarounds like giving the app direct access to the database circumventing AD authorization.
The second problem is that the application inherits all my access privileges, which it does not need since it loads data to temporary tables. I understand that I can register the application with the Azure AD and obtain an access token. However, I do not know what to do next.

Comment: [Using Azure Active Directory authentication with SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#customizing-active-directory-authentication) and [How to connect Azure SQL database from Python Function App using managed identity or access token](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-connect-azure-sql-database-from-python-function-app-using/ba-p/3035595)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to type in my password and authorization code every time I use the application. I want the application to get authenticated automatically.

- *You can use Active Directory Integrated Authentication method to login to your appication automatically.*
- *For this you need to federate your on-premises active directory instance with Azure AD.*
- *With this if you are signing into a domain-joined machine. You can access Azure SQL data sources without being prompted for credentials with this mode.*
- *But you can't set the credential property of sqlconnection.*
- *For more information you can refer this [Microsoft Document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-integrated-authentication)*
- *Also, as you are referring Access tokens here is the [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-connect-azure-sql-database-from-python-function-app-using/ba-p/3035595) with complete information.*